# Evaluate a dynamic array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that allows the user to add information an their leisure. They can add locations via jQuery in my form so when recieving the data I may have 1 location or 10. Each location has attributes like phone, address, etc. In my form the input names are appended with _1 , _2, etc to show its a new set of data. That is working swimmingly and I just can't seem to find these keys when looping through the $_POST array

```
private function array_pluck($arr,$text)
    {
        foreach($arr as $key => $item)
        {
            if(stripos($key,$text) != 0)
            {
                $found[] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $found;
    }
```

As I understand it if my array has some keys "office_branch_phone_1, office_branch_phone_2" I should be able to put in "office_branch" in my $text param and it will spit out any keys with the "office_branch" in the name. This isn't working however and I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: First off make sure $_POST looks like what you expect it to be in the form submission by either `print_r($_POST)` or via a debugger. My first  guess would be that your $arr isn't associative.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($arr) and see the contents of the $_POST[] ?
Also you should do stripos($key,$text) !== false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos) will return the index (and it is a 0-based index returned) `!= 0` is incorrect.

```
if (stripos($key,$text) !== false)
```

Would be the correct way to check it. Give that a shot.

**EDIT**

Note the use of `!==` instead of `!=` since 0 tends to be considered `false` if loosely checked the `!==` will check the actual type, so 0 is a valid return. Just an extra tidbit of information